# Как задать тень верхнему бордеру?

Tags: border, box-shadow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья подскажите как задать тень верхнему бордеру, все перепробовал, и внутреннюю и наружнюю, вот такие варианты работаю криво

```css
.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  
}
.menu__item {
      border-top: 1px solid transparent;
      line-height: 60px;
      
      height: 60px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
.menu__item:hover {
    content: "";
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0 rgba(224, 177, 122, 0.7) inset;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0b17a;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__list">
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через псеводэлементы:

```css
.menu__list {
  display: flex;
}

.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu__item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: tranpsarent;
}

.menu__item:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px 1px rgba(224, 177, 122, 0.9);
  background: #e0b17a;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__list">
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu__item">
      <a class="menu__link">Главная</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище ! выручил !